# How filter required data from response of a request by using Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have some response of a get request stored in a variable as below...

```
dashboard = 'http://12.345.67.890:8000/api/search?query=&starred=false'
dashboardr = s.get(dashboard)
dashboards = dashboardr.content
print(dashboards)
```

The response looks as below...

```
[{"id":19,"title":"Apple","uri":"db/abc-api","type":"dash-db","tags":[],"isStarred":false},{"id":20,"title":"Banana","uri":"db/cde-api","type":"dash-db","tags":[],"isStarred":false},{"id":7,"title":"Mango","uri":"db/efg","type":"dash-db","tags":[],"isStarred":false}]
```

Can some one please help me how we can extract the values of title and stored in another variable?

Title values in the above response are

```
Apple
Banana
Mango
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval(dashboards) instead of dashboards.

```
dashboard = 'http://12.345.67.890:8000/api/search?query=&starred=false'
dashboardr = s.get(dashboard)
# eval() will convert a string to a python statement/expression
dashboards = eval(dashboardr.content)

title_list = []
for _ in dashboards:
   title_list.append(dashboards["title"])
```

Comment: I am getting error as 

    dashboards = eval(dashboardr.content)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'false' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in eval(dashboards.replace('false', 'False')):
    print(i['title'])
```

instead of printing title you can save it in a list variable.

Comment: This is not enough to answer the question, it only fixes the second part of the question not how to parse the response.

Comment: When implemented i am getting error 
        print(i['title'])
    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: With the eval function included i am getting 

'    for i in eval(a):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'false' is not defined'

Comment: It's because you have a lower case "false" here instead of "False". You can fix this using the .replace method. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the response you from the HTTP call is a string, the code below extract the titles.

```
import json

response_str = '[{"id": 19, "title": "Apple", "uri": "db/abc-api", "type": "dash-db", "tags": [], "isStarred": false},{"id": 20, "title": "Banana", "uri": "db/cde-api", "type": "dash-db", "tags": [], "isStarred": false},{"id": 7, "title": "Mango", "uri": "db/efg", "type": "dash-db", "tags": [], "isStarred": false}]'
response_dict = json.loads(response_str)
titles = [entry['title'] for entry in response_dict]
print(titles)
```

Output:

```
[u'Apple', u'Banana', u'Mango']
```